# Eclipse "Open super implementation" across Android libraries?

Tags: android, eclipse

How can I make Eclipse open an Android library project's source file when clicking on
"Open Declaration" from the Android project that uses said library, instead of an
absurdly "decompiled" .class file-like rendition which I can't modify in place?

Steps to reproduce:

- Create Android library project A
- Create standard Android project B
- From project B, reference project A
- Override a protected method from A in B
- In B, click "Open super implementation", go to A, try to modify the source

Software:

- Eclipse Version: 4.2.1 Build id: M20120914-1800
- Android Development Toolkit Version: 21.0.0.v201210310015-519525
- OS X version: 10.8.2
- m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse   1.2.0.20120903-1050

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial answer: to not see the 'absurdly decompiled class file', click on the "Attach Source" on the same page (the class file like rendition) and select the source folder of the library you are using. But this is not editable.

Comment: But... why is the tool not capable of pointing to the right source file? I tried to do the same with Indigo and it worked, although with another set of plugins... Juno fails to see the obvious?

Comment: @Robottinosino m2e plugin is able to locate some sources even when its not a project with Maven facet.

Comment: That is installed, but the problem remains: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.2.0.20120903-1050